# Scanning a string a repeatedly amount of times and printing number of consonants in each line

Tags: c, arrays, character

I am trying to write a function `int count_consonants(char str[])` in c that determines and returns the number of consonants in a given string. Then from the `main()` function I want to repeatedly enter a string and then call the function `count_consonants(char str[])` to print the number of consonants per string entered. The program should stop execution once an entered sting is empty (only contains '\n'). I can't figure out the part where I can repeatedly enter strings and then store them individually to count the consonants in each of the string entered.

This is what my code looks like: (i realize that by entering a string with the while loop the only string that will be 'saved' is the last line only containing '\n.') How do i fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int count_consonants(char str[]){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++){
        if (str[i] != 'a' || str[i] != 'e' || 
            str[i] != 'i' || str[i] != 'o' || 
            str[i] != 'u' || str[i] != 'A' || 
            str[i] != 'E' || str[i] != 'I' ||
            str[i] != 'O' || str[i] != 'U' ||
            str[i] != ' ') {
                count++;
            }
    } 
    return count;
}

int main(){
    char str[100]
    while(str[0] != '\n'){
         fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    printf("Number of consonants=%d\n", count_consonants(str));
```

}

The input should look like this:

```
Hello world
this 
last
```

And out put should look like this:

```
Number of consonants=7
Number of consonants=3
Number of consonants=3
```

Comment: Please don’t tag C# when working with C, they’re different languages. Please edit and fix the tag

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're actually asking. My answer 'fixes' some errors in your code but maybe you wanted to do something else with the strings, once you've entered them and counted their consonants? Please clarify, and I can edit or change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your code, some trivial, some fundamental. The code below will work, and I've added comments where I made changes:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 

int count_consonants(char str[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++) { // You need && in place of all || ...
        if (str[i] != 'a' && str[i] != 'e' &&
            str[i] != 'i' && str[i] != 'o' &&
            str[i] != 'u' && str[i] != 'A' &&
            str[i] != 'E' && str[i] != 'I' &&
            str[i] != 'O' && str[i] != 'U' &&
            str[i] != ' ') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main() {
    char str[100]; // You've missed the terminating ; here!
    while (str[0] != '\n') {
        fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
        if (str[0] == '\n') break; // Jump out of the loop!
        printf("Number of consonants=%d\n", count_consonants(str));
    }
    return 0; // Always return an integer from main!
}
```

Other than the two 'typo' changes in the `main` function, you need to make a major change in the way you count consonants. In your original code, the `if` test will always be true, as only one of the `!=` comparisons can be false.

EDIT: Allow me to elaborate! Let's assume the first character in the test string is the letter `a` (a vowel, so we don't want to increment `count`). In the list of tests (where `i` will be `0`, so I'll use this index), according to **your code**, the first comparison: `str[0] != 'a'` will give `false` (as expected); however, *all subsequent comparisons*, such as the second: `str[0] != 'e'` will give `true` (because it isn't `e`, it's `a`), so the overall value of ***all*** tests will be: `false` OR `true` OR `true` OR `true` OR ...; thus, the `if` block will be entered and count will be incremented. This will be the same for any character: it can't be equal to all of your tests!

However, if you use the same tests but combine them with `&&`, the overall value of the tests will be `false` if **any one of the single tests is `false`**.

Feel free to ask for further explanation on how to concatenate `||` and `&&` comparison operators.

A far more concise implementation of `count_constants()` makes use of string/character handling functions provide by the `C` standard:

```
int count_consonants(char str[]) {
    int count = 0;
    const char *UCconsonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++) {
        if (strchr(UConsonants, toupper(str[i])) != NULL) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: yes this code works! however, could you please clarify why I would need the && (AND) instead of the || (OR). Also, what could I add to keep the program from printing "Number of consonants = 0" once i have entered the final string ('\n')?

Comment: @HannahMcDermott I've added some further clarification about using `&&` instead of `||` - hope this helps! I've also added a line that will allow you to breaks out of the loop (avoid printing) when a newline on its own is given.

Comment: Thankyou! and is there a way to make the if statement exclude all the characters that are not consonants in a shorter manner? i.e, instead of specifying that str[i] != 'a' for all vowels, numbers, spaces, and special characters?

Comment: There are many ways to make the code more concise; the obvious one in your case would be to use the function `strchr(s, c)` - which looks for the first occurrence of the character `c` in the string `s`, and returns `NULL` if it can't find one. So, `if (strchr("AEIOU", str[i] == NULL)` will be true if 'str[i]` is *not* an uppercase vowel. Several different ways to use `strchr`, though